# I am trying to include india map in my highchart code

Tags: highcharts

I am using the following code but getting an error as map not in list

I have also used hcmap instead of hc_add_series_map for the below code but still getting error as map not in list

```
`mudra_state <- mudra %>%
 group_by(State,Loan.Type) %>%
summarize(sum(Sanctioned.Amt),sum(Disbursement.Amt),sum(No.Of.Sanctions))

highchart() %>%
     hc_title(text = "Mudra Loans in India") %>%
     hc_subtitle(text = "Source: mudra.csv") %>%
 hc_add_series_map("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/india.geojson", mudra_state,
                       name  = c("State","Loan.Type"),
                       value = c("sum(Sanctioned.Amt)","sum(Disbursement.Amt)","sum(No.Of.Sanctions)"),
                       joinBy = c("woename", "State")) %>%
     hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T)`
```

Error: map is not a list

Answer (score 0):

I would use comments, but cannot paste the formatted code there. I will edit my answer if necessary.

I think you can't fetch your map like in your example. I was able to get your map this way:

```
library(highcharter)
indiageojson <- content(GET("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/india.geojson"))
indiageojson <- jsonlite::fromJSON(indiageojson)
indiageojson <- geojsonio::as.json(indiageojson)
highchart(type = "map") %>%
  hc_add_series(mapData = indiageojson)
```

Comment: as.json function does not work in geojsonio library.  Secondly, mapData is not a command in highchart library.  As a result following commands have error while running  the above code.                                                                            indiageojson <- geojsonio::as.json(indiageojson)                       hc_add_series(mapData = indiageojson)

Comment: mapData is certainly the property in Highcahrts library: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.mapData
And the above code works in my environment.
Maybe I'm missing something, but due to the fact you haven't even asked a specific question, I don't know how I can help you more.